# im trying to create a new user but it dosent work

Tags: adduser

After running `sudo adduser charlie`, I get:

```
Adding user `charlie' ...
Adding new group `charlie' (1002) ...
Adding new user `charlie' (1001) with group `charlie' ...
Creating home directory `/home/charlie' ...
Stopped: chown 1001:1002 /home/charlie: Invalid argument

Removing directory `/home/charlie' ...
Removing user `charlie' ...
Removing group `charlie' ...
groupdel: group 'charlie' does not exist
adduser: `groupdel charlie' returned error code 6. Exiting.
```

#### Further details

`sudo grpck -r` and `sudo pwck -rq` return nothing.

```
$ sudo egrep -i '1001|1002|charlie' /etc/{passwd,shadow,group}
/etc/passwd:charlie:x:1001:1002::/home/charlie: 
/etc/group:chronos-access:x:1001:jeffylaine
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99052/discussion-on-question-by-charlie-laine-im-trying-to-create-a-new-user-but-it-do).

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the comments that have now been moved to chat. Comments are very hard to read and easy to miss, so everything really should be in the actual question.